# Ensure that generic type only has primitive properties in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a function that takes a generic type, and i need to ensure that that type is JSON-serializable (aka only primitive properties).

My attempt at this was to define an interface for what a JSON compatible type looks like, and enforce that my generic extends this type:

```js
type JSONPrimitive = string | number | boolean | null
interface JSONObject {
  [prop: string]: JSONPrimitive | JSONPrimitive[] | JSONObject | JSONObject[]
}
export type JSONable = JSONObject | JSONPrimitive | JSONObject[] | JSONPrimitive[]

function myFunc<T extends JSONable>(thing: T): T {
  ...
}

// Elsewhere

// I know that if this was defined as a `type` rather than
// an `interface` this would all work, but i need a method
// that works with arbitrary types, including external interfaces which
// are out of my control
interface SomeType {
  id: string,
  name: string
}

myFunc<SomeType[]>(arrayOfSomeTypes)
// The above line doesn't work, i get: 
// Type 'SomeType[]' does not satisfy the constraint 'JSONable'.
//   Type 'SomeType[]' is not assignable to type 'JSONObject[]'.
//     Type 'SomeType' is not assignable to type 'JSONObject'.
//       Index signature is missing in type 'SomeType'.ts(2344)
```

The issue here seems to come down to the way index signatures work in typescript. Specifically, a type cannot extend a type with an index signature if it narrows the possible properties that the index signature allows. (ie `SomeType` doesn't allow you to arbitrarily add a `foo` property, but `JSONable` of course would. This issue is described further in this [existing github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1897).

So i know that the above doesn't really work, but the problem still persists that i need some reliable way to ensure that a generic type is JSON serializable. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The way I'd probably proceed here (in the absence of a fix or change to the [underlying issue around implicit index signatures in interfaces](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300)) would be to represent your desired json type as something like a generic constraint like this:

```
type AsJson<T> = 
  T extends string | number | boolean | null ? T : 
  T extends Function ? never : 
  T extends object ? { [K in keyof T]: AsJson<T[K]> } : 
  never;
```

So `AsJson<T>` should be equal to `T` if `T` is a valid JSON type, otherwise it will have `never` in its definition somewhere.  Then we can do this:

```
declare function myFunc<T>(thing: T & AsJson<T>): T;
```

which requires that `thing` be `T` (which infers `T` for you) *intersected* with `AsJson<T>`, which adds `AsJson<T>` as an additional constraint on `thing`.  Let's see how it works:

```
myFunc(1); // okay
myFunc(""); // okay
myFunc(true); // okay
myFunc(null); // okay

myFunc(undefined); // error
myFunc(() => 1); // error
myFunc(console.log()); // error

myFunc({}); // okay
myFunc([]); // okay
myFunc([{a: [{b: ""}]}]); // okay

myFunc({ x: { z: 1, y: () => 1, w: "v" } }); // error!
//  --------------> ~
//  () => number is not assignable to never
```

And now your interface type is accepted:

```
interface SomeType {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}

const arrayOfSomeTypes: SomeType[] = [{ id: "A", name: "B" }];
myFunc(arrayOfSomeTypes); // okay
```

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAggzgKTgewHYB4AqA+KBeKAKCikyggA9gJUATOKOYAJwEtUBzKAHylQFcAtgCMIzHlGHJkAGwgBDVBIEyZUAPykoALiIkylanQYAxfqgDGwVmg18IANzE69WwzXpRkwgFYQrdgDeUADaANJQ7FAA1hAgyABmpAC6uvBIaFjhybgAvi7E9k7MANyEhLT+MvLM0AnmVjZKgiBmlljYABTAABbsHLpkAGSwiCgYOACUg2WELW0WnQCMkyVQAPTrXtHyIHOtDZ0AREerG1vIO3vzhyz8EGeb27v7C50qMo8XV+U3lp3mSoJdgQWhfcjMZjIZivQ6dSb4XArNZPMRQmF-RYWNAoOQAOhkyA48PBaOhvwO-0CuXBlxemM6IWStJ+DJCgXkunZwl0J1yyX5LJesKpUAoumCAC9dEsADRQEC6eGIqByqAAd15DiOUHyNJRWzJzAAhIQnlAALRW602m24AB+Zq2UGVeFwAhEzlYDFQyGAUHkcDgrA4qHkwjkUGAyCKYnKhHY1GYCXkFmgAGVkIIIJhwNBAoVWLRdEw2JwyiQw9mSyx+mVcuVsagmAHIbsAPIJTPZ3OQOC6bs5vNM-ChYJF3kwI7yqsQXkAIR1-LKDJqzA7XazQ77Qr2QA)

Comment: You sir, are a genius! Really neat solution and it seems to work seamlessly for me!