# What is the JSON interface in Typescript

Tags: json, typescript

Why does the following snippet not compile, and how is the ES6 JSON interface supposed to be used?

```js
let myVar: JSON = {"id": "12"};
```

Gives the following error message: `Type '{ id: string; }' is not assignable to type 'JSON'. Object literal may only specify known properties, and '"id"' does not exist in type 'JSON'.`

My IDE gives the following definition for JSON, but I can’t understand it:

```js
interface JSON {
    readonly [Symbol.toStringTag]: string;
}
```

Comment: `JSON` is a reserved name already in use (by the object that provides `JSON.parse`). Use some other name. Note that JSON is simply a string until it is parsed, then it is an object.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I initialize a TypeScript Object with a JSON-Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22885995/how-do-i-initialize-a-typescript-object-with-a-json-object)

Comment: If you are looking for a `type` to enforce an object to be compatible with JSON (by containing only primitves/arrays/objects) this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57858862/8613630) may help you.

Comment: Aside, I'd use numbers for numbers, also in JSON, `'{"id": 12}'`.

Comment: The interrogation stemmed from looking for a (native)JSON type in Typescript, and the best answer I could find on the subject was this one: [TypeScript - How to model a JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63085332/9450152)
But my question remained after that, I couldn’t understand what this JSON interface was. The answers now clarify this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JSON` is a global object [defined by the JS specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-json-object) designed to hold the `parse` and `stringify` methods for converting between JS data structures and JSON texts.

It isn't a type. It isn't supposed to be used as one.

---

When creating a custom object format, you are supposed to define your own type (although it isn't useful to do so here, but might be if you define a function elsewhere that you need to pass the object to as an argument). When dealing with JSON, you are dealing with strings.

```
type MyFormat = {
    id: string;
}

let myVar: MyFormat = {"id": "12"};
let myJSON: string = JSON.stringify(myVar);
```

Comment: Aside, I'd use numbers for numbers, also in JSON, `{"id": 12}`. (Just confused by "When dealing with JSON, you are dealing with strings" while later I saw the `"12"` was taken from the question.)

Comment: @Arjan — So would I, but I wasn't going to complicate matters by redesigning the OP's data structure in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

There's no reason you'd use the `JSON` interface in your code. It relates to the [`JSON`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) built-in object, and there's no reason to use that object other than using its `parse` and/or `stringify` methods to parse or create JSON text.

From your code, you appear to misunderstand what JSON is. (*Lots* of people do! :-) ) JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript or TypeScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Your `myVar` refers to an *object*. There's no need to put a type annotation on it, you can just let TypeScript infer it from the initializer, but if you wanted to put a type annotation on it you'd use either `{id: string;}` or `Record<string, string>` or some other [object type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#object-types):

```
// Letting TypeScript infer
let myVar = {"id": "12"};
// Or specify an object with an `id` property of type string
let myVar: {id: string;} = {"id": "12"};
// Or create a type alias and use it
type MyVarType = {
    id: string;
};
let myVar: MyVarType = {"id": "12"};
// Or perhaps an object where any string is a valid property name and the types are all strings
let myVar: Record<string, string> = {"id": "12"};
```

See the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#object-types) linked above for more about object types.

---

Side note: If you meant to use a number for `id`, you'd use `id: number` or similar:

```
let myVar: {id: number;} = {id: 12};
```